# Receiving 'Operation aborted error' when adding label to existing issue using jira api via vba even though label is successfully added

Tags: vba, excel, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to add a label to an existing issue in JIRA using the JIRA REST API via VBA. I can successfully login, get the session id/cookie, find the issue, and add a comment to the issue, but when I try to add a label I receive the following error message in Excel

[image: Error Message]

However, the funny thing is the label is actually added

Before macro:

[image: Before]

After macro:

[image: After]

I just can't explain or figure out what's going on. I've scoured the Internet (particularly the Atlassian forums) and have come across pages with examples that suggest I'm sending this request properly, but I still receive this Run-time error. Among many things here are a few things I've read/do to try and figure this out

- I've done a `GET` on the issue's `/editmeta` to get the details for the `labels` field, which produced this

  ```
  labels":{  
     "required":false,
     "schema":{  
        "type":"array",
        "items":"string",
        "system":"labels"
     },
     "name":"Labels",
     "autoCompleteUrl":"http://jira.company.local:8080/rest/api/1.0/labels/suggest?query=",
     "operations":[  
        "add",
        "set",
        "remove"
     ]
  }
  ```

So, according to that I *should* be able to use the "add" verb to add the label

- The method I'm using (found at the bottom of this question) was adapted from user *Patrick Patrick*'s comments from [this thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/27182/excel-vba-jira-rest-api)
- I've read the documentation on editing data from [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-edit-issues)
- Learned that I should be using PUT instead of POST from [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/33522/method-not-allowed-when-post-not-allowed-when-trying-to-update-jira-issue-via-rest-api)
- Read specifically about how to update labels and followed the syntax from [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis), then tried the new method described in the response [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/248307/405-method-not-allowed-when-updating-via-editmeta)
- Finally, I found a bundle of bugs all related to this sort of issue floating around the Atlassian community. Branching out from [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-27929)

So, that's where I'm at. My Question is simply this:

**How can I add the label without receiving the Run-time error every time? It seems a bit pointless if my macro stops every time it adds one label to one issue**

Below are the appropriate pieces of code that I am using.

*JIRA* Module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub JIRA()
    Dim ASNumber As String, Supplier As String, IssueLink As String
    Dim myJIRA As New clsJIRARest
    With myJIRA
        .UserName = "******"
        .Password = "******"
        .URL = "http://jira.company.local:8080"
        If .Login = False Then Exit Sub
        .GetLastSummary
        IssueLink = .GetIssueLink '<-works fine
        ASNumber = .GetASNumber '<-works fine
        Supplier = .GetSupplierName '<-works fine
        .PostExportComment '<-Throws run-time error 'Operation aborted'
        .Logout
    End With

End Sub
```

Appropriate parts of *clsJIRARest* Class Module:

```
Public Function Login() As Boolean

    Login = False

    With JiraAuth
        .Open "POST", sURL & "/rest/auth/1/session", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"

        .send " {""username"" : """ & sJIRAUserID & """, ""password"" : """ & sJIRAPass & """}"" '*** HTTP-Request senden"

        sErg = .responseText

        If .Status = "200" Then
            sCookie = "JSESSIONID=" & Mid(sErg, 42, 32) & "; Path=/" & sPfad
            Login = True
        End If

    End With

End Function

Public Function GetLastSummary()

    Dim myRegEx As Object: Set myRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    myRegEx.Global = True
    myRegEx.Pattern = "as\/([0-9]{4,5}).+?(?=\-)" '<-Working
    With JiraService
        .Open "GET", sURL & "/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=mhill+order+by+lastViewed&now&maxResults=5", False
       .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
       .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
       .setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", sCookie '*** see Create a "Cookie"

        .send
        Set sRestAntwort = myRegEx.Execute(.responseText)
        Sup = sRestAntwort(0)
        ANum = sRestAntwort(0).Submatches(0)

        myRegEx.Pattern = "self"":""(.+?(?=""))"
        myRegEx.Global = False
        Set sRestAntwort = myRegEx.Execute(.responseText)
        sIssueLink = sRestAntwort(0).Submatches(0)
    End With

End Function

'The comment posts fine below, but the label is what causes the error
Public Function PostExportComment() As Boolean
    With JiraService
        .Open "POST", sIssueLink & "/comment", False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", sCookie '*** see Create a "Cookie"
        Dim sExportComment As String: sExportComment = "Full Export Requested - Awaiting Download Email"
        .send " {""body"" : """ & sExportComment & """}"" '*** HTTP-Request senden"
'
'        PostExportComment = IIf(.Status = "201", True, False)

        .Open "PUT", sIssueLink, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", sCookie '*** see Create a "Cookie"
        Dim sExportingLabel As String: sExportingLabel = "Exporting"
        '===============Errors on next line==================
        .send " { ""update"": { ""labels"": [{""add"": """ & sExportingLabel & """}] } }"" '*** HTTP-Request senden" '(See below photo for error message)
        Debug.Print .Status & "|" & .statusText
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: If the error is on the API side, and it's meaningless, ...why not just swallow it? (wrap the failing line with `On Error Resume Next` {code} `On Error GoTo 0`)

Comment: I suppose I could, It's just that way just seems a bit dirty to me, you know? Shouldn't there be a cleaner way?

Comment: I don't know Jira's API, but can you repro the error with minimal code that does just that - i.e. try to isolate the behavior from everything else around it. If it works but still throws that error, I suppose the bug is on Jira's side, not yours.

Comment: That's just what I did. I went through and commented out surrounding code and it just errors on the `.send` call that's adding the label. I mean, it does seem to be an issue Jira is aware of according to those bug issues in the links I've posted. It just sucks they're not doing anything about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems they're giving you a specific error code for this. That's great, because you can ignore *that one* and still handle other possible errors - and if that error number isn't *specific* to the "PostExportComment" action, then make yourself a local variable to track where the error is happening:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    '...

        currentStep = "PostExportComment"
        .PostExportComment '<-Throws run-time error 'Operation aborted'
        currentStep = "Logout"
        .Logout
    End With

CleanExit:
    'clean up here
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    '"Operation aborted" error is a false positive, see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-27929
    If currentStep = "PostExportComment" And Err.Number = -2147467260 Then
        Resume Next 
    Else
        'handle other possible runtime errors here
        Resume CleanExit
    End If
```

...or better, wrap the 3rd-party API in a class module and handle that error neatly in your own wrapper for `PostExportComment`:

```
Private wrapped As My3rdPartyThing

Public Enum MeaningfulError
    ERR_FoobarNotInitialized = vbObjectError + 42
    ERR_WrongCredentials
    ERR_Whatever
End Enum

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set wrapped = New My3rdPartyThing
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set wrapped = Nothing
End Sub

'wraps the "GetFoo" API method
Public Function GetFoo(ByVal bar As Long) As Something
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set GetFoo = wrapped.GetFoo(bar)

    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 12345 Then 
        Err.Raise ERR_FoobarNotInitialized
    Else
        Err.Raise ERR_Whatever
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh, very clever! Then again, it always is when it's coming from you :) Just one question, what do you mean by wrapping the API in a class module and handling the error that way? I only ask because as it stands right now I have all of the API functionality in a class module *already* (see my *clsJIRARest* Class Module). Is that what you meant? I just now realized I forgot to label it clearly as a *Class* Module, which I'll promptly fix. Anyway, how do you suggest I go about that better/cleaner option?

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder I've added an example wrapper

Comment: Thanks for the example!